# tflite-model-maker infinite install

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

at this page

https://colab.research.google.com/github/khanhlvg/tflite_raspberry_pi/blob/main/object_detection/Train_custom_model_tutorial.ipynb#scrollTo=35BJmtVpAP_n

when i run these commands:

!pip install -q tflite-model-maker
!pip install -q tflite-support

tflite-model-maker infinite download and install
why? and where is the problem?

solving this problem as soon as

Comment: take a look at this temporary solution
https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tflite-model-maker-installation/16577/3

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the following commands:

```
!pip install tflite-model-maker
!pip install tflite-support
```

To see what's going on behind.